# Specialist died before developing weapon

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I had the Anaesthesia specialist from mission 10 in my staff but some time later he died due to injuries...

I still have some weapons that require his specialty to be developed, should I just replay mission 10 or is there another anaesthesia specialist elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, if you lost Malak, you need to replay mission 10** if you want to make use of his<sup>*</sup> unique skills.

Replaying the mission allows you to bring him back (confirmed [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/718564-metal-gear-solid-v-the-phantom-pain/72421544?page=1#20) and [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/287700/discussions/0/527274088391268778/)).

There are a couple of **causes** that can make you lose (sight of) him:

- [He was directly transferred to the sickbay](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/718564-metal-gear-solid-v-the-phantom-pain/72421544?page=1#17).
- [He was kicked out of a full waiting room](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/718564-metal-gear-solid-v-the-phantom-pain/72570670#4).
- [He got killed during combat deployment](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/718564-metal-gear-solid-v-the-phantom-pain/72570670#2).

And [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264904/finding-anesthesia-specialist)'s another SE question dealing with Malak.

<sup>* At higher ranks he can be replaced by a similar NPC with a different name - like '[Cannibal Hog](https://steamcommunity.com/app/287700/discussions/0/412447613564875580#c412447613564959520)', apparently.</sup>

Comment: Great! In my case he went straight to the sickbay after getting rescued, then died there... I think now my Med staff is larger, perhaps he doesn't die this time.